# AWS Cloudfront causing CSRF Token Mismatch Exception

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

Alright hello, I have deployed my Laravel app on AWS ELB and I set up Cloudfront distribution for my app. Now I am facing CSRF Token mismatch. I know that this error can be caused by multiple config values that may be wrong. Now I have managed to fix this issue by myself in the past, but it was a long time ago and I don't know what I did and where. So if you have some tips on what could be wrong and where, then definitely send them my way. Thanks

**EDIT:** The exception happens after switching to Cloudfront. My problem is to get it working with Cloudfront.

Comment: Is this when trying to submit a form or what?

Comment: @Option Yeah, it happens when I submit the form. Sorry, forgot to mention it. It never happened to me on any other occasion.

Comment: add `{{ csrf_field() }}` under the open `<form>` tags

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the problem was with forwarding of cookies, especially the `XSRF_TOKEN` cookie. Cookies aren't forwarded by default through the cloudfront, you have to set up a whitelist to do that. Just edit the cloudfront distribution it's in Behaviours section. Another cookies to consider forwarding are `laravel_session` if you use cookie sessions and `remember_*` if you use remember login feature.

Comment: +1k Just spent a week trying to figure this one out and it finally dawned on me it was probably something to do with AWS Cloudfront and found your post. Sending you a big 'ol hug!!!

Answer (score 0):

- Edit your distribution, select **Behaviors** tab and then create behavior
- select your Origin
- On **Origin request policy - optional** click on **Create origin request policy**
- Name your request policy and choose **ALL** in cookies drop down
- click create and return to Behavior creation
- Select the created Origin request policy
- Save changes