CloudFront Origin return 403 when cache is enabled
I configured AWS CloudFront in front of ALB and for specific url get 403 error. Example of curl request
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  -H 'baggage: sentry-trace_id=xxxxxxx,sentry-sample_rate=1,sentry-public_key=xxxxxxxx,sentry-environment=xxxxxx,sentry-sampled=true' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'cookie: _gid=GA1.2.1776819646.1735124930; _gat_gtag_UA_74594092_2=1; _gcl_au=1.1.1331080841.1735124931; SSESSa34f7a05d9d3fsdfsdfsdf=56465465465; _ga_D9NGDWR4JE=GS1.1.1735124930.1.1.1735124951.0.0.0; _ga=GA1.2.1918087349.1735124930' \
  -H 'origin: https://example.com' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'priority: u=1, i' \
  -H 'referer: https://example.com/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Not A(Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="132", "Google Chrome";v="132"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sentry-trace: 36fa2026ea6-8b1408cd355b2fe4-1' \
  -H 'x-csrf-token: Xasdasdas0HQdassadasdasdaeY-fGMt0VjiqGrdMVGVSY
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/132.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --data-raw '{"ids":[21119,11171,1117}'

I have a default behavior that redirects to origin(ALB). The cache policy is CacheOptimazed and the Origin request policy is AllViewer. There is only 1 specific request on the site that fails and returns the error {"message":"X-CSRF-Token request header is invalid"}%. When I disable the cache (caching policy: CacheDisabled), everything works as expected. How to fix this with caching enabled. The application is written in Drupal.

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865338/aws-cloudfront-causing-csrf-token-mismatch-exception

my application is written in drupal. And even adding XSRF_TOKEN cookie to cache policy doesn't help
